how building hadoop source code on macos m2 chip
I am trying to build hadoop source code on macOS(m2 chip) the system version macOS Ventura.
The problem:
 ld: warning: ignoring file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
[WARNING] ld: warning: ignoring file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
[WARNING] ld: warning: ignoring file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
[WARNING] ld: Undefined symbols:
[WARNING]   _JNI_CreateJavaVM, referenced from:
[WARNING]       _getGlobalJNIEnv in libhdfs.a[3](jni_helper.c.o)
[WARNING]   _JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs, referenced from:
[WARNING]       _getGlobalJNIEnv in libhdfs.a[3](jni_helper.c.o)
[WARNING] ld: Undefined symbols:
[WARNING]   _JNI_CreateJavaVM, referenced from:
[WARNING]       _getGlobalJNIEnv in libhdfs.a[3](jni_helper.c.o)
[WARNING]   _JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs, referenced from:
[WARNING]       _getGlobalJNIEnv in libhdfs.a[3](jni_helper.c.o)
[WARNING] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


These seem to be warnings. What's the problem?

For starters, you'll want to use Java 11 at least

required architecture 'x86_64'

Use an amd64 VM or container to do the build (and run Hadoop).
The version you're trying to compile doesn't support ARM
